# Issue with discord.py and heroku hosting

Tags: python, heroku, discord.py

Good day, I am making a discord bot in my free time using discord.py. I recently added a command that allows me to grab a .txt file from a specific location and send the contents of this file as a message in the discord chat. On my desktop this works great. But when I upload it to github and then deploy the branch to heroku for hosting, the .txt are suddenly not being read anymore. I cannot see any error codes. But I assume it gives errors of "file not found".

```
   async def chelp(self, ctx, name = 'help'):
        name = name.lower()
        file = open(f'cogs/chelp/{name}.txt', 'r')
        message = file.read()
        await ctx.send(message.format(ctx.author.name))
        await ctx.message.delete()
```

log file from a run

```
2020-05-19T12:23:25.719698+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Restarting
2020-05-19T12:23:25.791450+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to starting
2020-05-19T12:23:32.796643+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-05-19T12:23:35.896952+00:00 app[worker.1]: Failed to load extension cogs.ErrorHandler.
2020-05-19T12:23:35.896970+00:00 app[worker.1]: Extension 'cogs.ErrorHandler' could not be loaded.
2020-05-19T12:23:35.899274+00:00 app[worker.1]: Failed to load extension cogs.CustomCommands.
2020-05-19T12:23:35.899310+00:00 app[worker.1]: Extension 'cogs.CustomCommands' could not be loaded.
2020-05-19T12:23:39.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-05-19T12:23:40.768514+00:00 app[worker.1]: Tekxit Bot#3667 has connected to Discord!
2020-05-19T12:23:40.768567+00:00 app[worker.1]: Username is Tekxit Bot
2020-05-19T12:23:40.768568+00:00 app[worker.1]: ID is 463770605699989515
2020-05-19T12:23:40.768569+00:00 app[worker.1]: Keep this window open to keep the bot running.
```

Comment: This may sound dumb, but have you checked if the text files are uploaded?

Comment: I checked the git page and everything is there and complete. Since the deploy is set to use the git page it will automatically copy-paste the entire branch I selected and I cannot view the file structure on Heroku.
No dumb questions in cases like these exist. Better to rule out the simple errors instead of searching for hours without finding anything.

Comment: Btw, you can check the logs of your deployment... try this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging I think it would be helpful to understand what's happening before doing something

Comment: @SwetankPoddar thanks for the suggestion. I now realized it does NOT load 2 of the cogs. Being the error handler and the file reader. I added logs to the original post.

Comment: Can you show your whole script? I have a strong feeling that the `cogs` error has nothing to do with the part of code you're showing here

Comment: I found out the issue. I will be posting it as an answer @SwetankPoddar. Thanks for trying to help me. :D

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the issue by myself. Apparently there was a difference between the git files and the local files on my PC. I figured this out after the cogs also failed to load on my laptop. Apparently in the 2 cogs that failed the capitalization of the cog names was different than what I set it to on my main desktop. Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this.